# Centering Text Fields in Kivy

Tags: kivy, center, kivy-language, textinput

[image: Want to center the TextInput fields]

The screen shot below represents a working Python program using Kivy. However, the Kivy descriptor file may be in error. I want the two text fields (the second and third lines) to be centered.

I would have thought `anchor_x:'center'` would do that, but I must be missing something.

You would think this would be easy, but I can't make it work. .kv descriptor file:

```
# Add two numbers layout code
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 1
    orientation:'vertical'
    pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
    background_color: .7,.7,.7,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .7, .7, .7, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

ColorLabel:
    text: "Enter two numbers to add"

TextInput:
    id: frnum
    size_hint: (None, .8)
    width: 150
    anchor_x: 'center'

TextInput:
    id: secnum
    size_hint: (None, .8)
    width: 150
    anchor_x: 'center'

# horizontal box contains two buttons
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 10
    orientation:'horizontal'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .7, .7, .7, 1

    GrayButton:
        text: 'Add'
        color: 0,0,0,1
        on_release:
            app.bclick()

    GrayButton:
        text: 'Clear'
        on_release:
            app.cclick()

ColorLabel:
    text: "Sum appears here"
    id: sumlabel

<ColorLabel@Label>:
    color: 0,0,1,1
    size: self.texture_size
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .9, .9, .9, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    padding_x: 20
    background_color: .7,.7,.7,1

<GrayButton@Button>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: .8,.8,.8,1
    padding_horizontal: 20
    size_hint: (0.5,0.7)
    pos_hint: {'x':.2, 'y':.2, 'center_x':.5}

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #self.title = "Add two numbers"
        Window.size = (300, 200)
        self.load_kv('Bldtest1.kv')

# Add click event
def bclick(self):
    textinput = self.root.ids.frnum
    val1= int(textinput.text)
    tinput = self.root.ids.secnum
    val2 = int(tinput.text)
    sum_label = self.root.ids.sumlabel
    sum_label.text = "Sum is: "+ str(val1+val2)

# Clear button click event
def cclick(self):
    textinput = self.root.ids.frnum
    textinput.text = ''
    tinput = self.root.ids.secnum
    tinput.text = ""
    sum_label = self.root.ids.sumlabel
    sum_label.text =''

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `anchor_x` attribute is used in the `AnchorLayout` class, not in a `TextInput`. Try replacing:

```
anchor_x: 'center'
```

with:

```
pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
```

See the [BoxLayout documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) concerning position hints:

Position hints are partially working, depending on the orientation:

- If the orientation is vertical: x, right and center_x will be used.
- If the orientation is horizontal: y, top and center_y will be used.